# Custom Marker in RadiusMarkerClusterer

Tags: android, kotlin, osmdroid, osmbonuspack

I created a customMarker that in addition to the image contains a label at the bottom with a name.
If I create a "**FolderOverlay**" everything works correctly I see my custom Marker.

This is my customMarker

```
class MarkerWithLabel(mapView: MapView?, val label: String) : Marker(mapView) {
val textPaint = Paint()

init {

    with(textPaint){
        color = Color.BLACK
        textSize = 35f
        isAntiAlias = true
        typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
        textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
    }
}

override fun draw(c: Canvas, osmv: MapView?, shadow: Boolean) {
    draw(c, osmv)
}



fun draw(c: Canvas, osmv: MapView?) {
    super.draw(c, osmv, false)
    val p: Point = mPositionPixels // already provisioned by Marker
    c.drawText(label, p.x.toFloat(), (p.y + 30).toFloat(), textPaint)
}
```

}

Creating a "**RadiusMarkerClusterer**" on the other hand does not show the label below the CustomMarker. Actually it seems that osmBonuspack does not use my CustomMarker but the normal Marker.

I say this because it does not override the draw method of my CustomMarker.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In MarkerClusterer.java, drawing piece code is as follow:

```
for (StaticCluster cluster:mClusters){
    cluster.getMarker().draw(canvas, mapView.getProjection());
```

As you can see, the method called is:
*public void draw(Canvas canvas, Projection pj)*

So you should try to override this method.